# Mathematica document not retaining margins from stylesheet when printing?

Tags: export, stylesheet

In the process of creating my resume in Mathematica, I needed to adjust the margins of the default stylesheet so that section headers would take up less whitespace. After modifying the stylesheet using the [instructions mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499975/176191), the changes clearly show up in my document in Mathematica.

[image: Before printing]

However, after I export the document to a PDF, either by saving or by printing, my work is undone.

[image: After printing document]

So I've resorted to copying and pasting screen captures of my resume into MSPaint and then printing from there. This is a huge pain.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a setting I have to modify to get my stylesheet margins to stick in the PDF version?

Comment: When printing (or saving to PDF), it uses the `Printout` screen environment, whereas what you see (by default) in the notebook is the `Working` screen environment. The changes to the style definitions that you've made are only for the working environment, whereas you need to modify it for the printout env. I don't have time to write an answer now, but this might give you a lead as to where to look (or someone else can write up an answer). Try exploring the `Default.nb` and `Core.nb` stylesheets to see how the styles for `Printout` are defined. If no one answers by this evening, I'll write one.

Comment: @rm-rf: I had similar issue, but when I change the PrintingStyleEnvironment to Working, I have issues with Margins and zoomed out document. I changed stuff in my notebook by using a stylesheet like you mentioned in one of your answers. How do I make the same changes to the Printout option privately only for that notebook?

Comment: @preeti Add the following to your stylesheet: `Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"],
 CellLabelMargins->Inherited,
 Magnification->1]`

Comment: @rm-rf That doesn't seem to do anything..My requirement : Printout should be having the same fontcolor etc as mentioned in my stylesheet. How do I do that?

Comment: @preeti You only mentioned margins and zoomout in your previous comment, so that's all I addressed. You should ask the right question with all details to get the right answer... :) Try adding `ShowAutoStyles->True` and 
`ShowSyntaxStyles->True` to the snippet I wrote above to display the colors. The idea here is that any change you want to make, you make it to the `StyleData[All, "Printout"]` style.

Comment: @rm-rf Thanks :) That does solve the syntax issue but I am still having problems with the margin. In my stylesheet I had put CellMargins, but the CellLabelMargins->Inherited doesn't seem to fix the margin issue.

Comment: @preeti Then try `CellMargins -> Inherited` or the same value that you used in your stylesheet.

Comment: @rm-rf neither works...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As rm -rf wrote the looks of the printout are by default determined by the `Printout` style definitions in the stylesheet, and you could try to change those.

However, if you don't feel like that, you could also try to change the printing environment from "Printout" to "Working", so that it uses the changes you already made for your screen layout. You can do that in  `File > Printing Settings > Printing Environment` or by executing

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

for a permanent change or

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

for a change that lasts as long as you session lasts.

Comment: Wound up changing the Printout style definitions. Thanks!