# PlotLegends and ImageSize

Tags: plotting, legending, pdf-format

I have *Mathematica* 9.0.1, and I have problems with `PlotLegends` breaking the `ImageSize` directive.

I defined

```
cm = 72 / 2.54;
```

to work with centimeters. I would like an output PDF with a width of, say, 9 cm.

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Exp[-4 f] /. {{f -> t}, {f -> t^2}}], {t, 0, 3}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 11, AbsoluteThickness[1.5]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t"},  
  PlotLabel -> "Negativity", 
  ImageSize -> 9 cm,  
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"OU", "FBM"}, {.8, .5}]]
Export["Neg_long_OU_FBM.pdf", %];
```

With this command, I obtain a PDF with size 6.48 × 4.31 cm. If I remove the `PlotLegends` option, I get the correct width of 9 cm. If I leave `PlotLegends` without the `Placed` directive (the legend is placed at the right of the Plot), I get 9.42 × 4.38 cm.

Is this an expected behavior? How can I produce an output PDF with a 9 cm width and the legend inside the plot?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but using `Export["Neg_long_OU_FBM.pdf", %, ImageSize -> 9 cm]`and not setting the `ImageSize` in the Plot gets you much closer.

Comment: I think that this is just a coincidence, as the output of Plot (without setting `ImageSize`) has a size of 9.15 cm. In fact I obtain the same result with `Export["...", %]`, `Export["...",%, ImageSize -> 9 cm ]` or `Export["...", %, ImageSize -> 2 cm]`

Comment: Ah very true indeed.

Comment: Problem still there in V 10.1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help.  Here I have a helper function to make the legend into an `Inset`:

```
plot = Plot[Evaluate[Exp[-4 f] /. {{f -> t}, {f -> t^2}}], {t, 0, 3}, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 11, AbsoluteThickness[1.5]}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, AxesLabel -> {"t"}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Negativity", 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"OU", "FBM"}, {.8, .5}], ImageSize -> 9 cm];

makeInset[plot_Legended] := 
 Show[{plot[[1]], 
   Graphics[
    Inset[plot[[2, 1, 1]], Scaled[plot[[2, 1, 2]]]]]}]
```

and then wrap `plot` with this function:

```
Export["Neg_long_OU_FBM.pdf", makeInset[plot]];
```

Comment: This workaround works like charm! I just had to slightly modify the Part of like this `makeInset[plot_Legended] := 
 Show[{plot[[1]], 
   Graphics[Inset[plot[[2, 1, 1]], Scaled[plot[[2, 1, 2]]]]]}]` to make it work with my code. Thank you! I'm still wondering if there are cleaner solutions!

Comment: Yes, sorry I see I was using a slightly different plot.  I will correct this.

Comment: On Mathematica 11.2 this works: `makeInset[plot_Legended] := Show[{plot[[1]], Graphics[Inset[plot[[2, 1]], Scaled[plot[[2, 2]]]]]}]`. (The code in the current answer fails with "Coordinate {"OU", "FBM"} should be a pair of numbers.")

Answer (score 1):

The problem is still present in Mathematica 10.3. and it appears also if plots are combined with `Grid` (or `Column`, ...) before being exported to a pdf. So maybe `PlotLegend` uses internally a `Grid`-like function.

Interestingly, the scaling factor 6.48 cm / 9 cm = 0.72 matches exactly the Magnification value of the default `Printout` environment (`Format` > `Edit Stylesheet...` > `Default.nb` > section `Style Environment Names` > select `Printout` > open `Option Inspector` > search `Magnification`). Therefore, this problem can be solved by choosing

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

the `Working` environment according to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11988/38534.